# Is the function, thread safe or not?

Tags: java

I am reading "Java concurrency in Practice". We have a function given below:

```
public class LazyInitRace {
   private ExpensiveObject instance = null;
   public ExpensiveObject getInstance() { 
       if (instance == null)
          instance = new ExpensiveObject(); 
       return instance;
   ￼￼} 
 }
```

Author says, that this not thread safe. Whereas I think, that "instance" variable is not a static one and therefore thread safe. 
I think it becomes thread unsafe only when the same instance of class is accessed by two threads. I need to know what I am thinking is correct or not?

Comment: if they are not static,then you need to new a object then use its getnstance,then singleton pattern will be meaningless

Comment: @FireSun: I don't think this is trying to do singleton, just trying to instantiate the `ExpensiveObject` only once per instance, and in one placed (`getInstance`). Granted `getInstance` is a fairly dodgy name for that method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the variable is non-`static` or `static`. The purpose is to have one per instance and create it only once.

This is not fullfilled here - when two parallel threads enter this method the variable may appear as `null` to both of them and both will create new instance. You need to wrap the code or method with `synchronized`.

Answer (score 2):

*Thread safety* is a computer programming concept applicable in the context of multi-threaded programs. A piece of code is thread-safe if it only manipulates shared data structures in a manner that guarantees safe execution by multiple threads at the same time.

```
class Singleton {

private volatile static Singleton _instance;

private Singleton() {
    // preventing Singleton object instantiation from outside 
}

/* 
 * 1st version: creates multiple instance if two thread access 
 * this method simultaneously 
 */

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
        _instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return _instance;
} 

/* 
 * 2nd version : this definitely thread-safe and only 
 *creates one instance of Singleton on concurrent environment 
 * but unnecessarily expensive due to cost of synchronization 
 * at every call. 
 */


public static synchronized Singleton getInstanceTS() {
    if (_instance == null) {
        _instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return _instance;
}
/* 
 * 3rd version : An implementation of double checked locking of Singleton. 
 * Intention is to minimize cost of synchronization and improve performance, 
 * by only locking critical section of code, the code which creates instance of Singleton class. 
 * By the way this is still broken, if we don't make _instance volatile, as another thread can 
 * see a half initialized instance of Singleton. 
 */

public static Singleton getInstanceDC() {
    if (_instance == null) {
        synchronized (Singleton.class) {
            if (_instance == null) {
                _instance = new Singleton();
            }
        }
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

}

Comment: Your example is only remotely related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

When we say a program is thread safe it means that all threads of that program have a **CONSISTENT** view of the values of the data in the program. Here's a simple example. Let's say `something` is an `ExpensiveObject` which has been initialized by the `getInstance` method and is visible to all threads of the program. Also, `classObject` is an object of type `Class<ExpensiveObject>`. Now consider the following code snippet run by some thread:

```
if(something != null)
  classObject = something.getClass();
```

It looks like a `NullPointerException` is impossible right? It's not. Between `if(something != null)` and `classObject = something.getClass();` another thread can change the value of `something` to `null`. THIS program would not be thread safe because reads and writes to `something` is not **synchronized** which makes sure all threads have a consistent view of `something`'s value.